# Is it possible to decrypt a Windows Security Catalog (.cat) using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Microsoft Security Catalog Format Documentation and API Samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598236/microsoft-security-catalog-format-documentation-and-api-samples)

I have been looking around as to whether it is possible to open and decrypt a Windows Security Catalog using C# and .NET.

My aim is to allow the contents of the .cat file to be humanly readable purely so that I can see what's inside. If this isn't possible, that information would be useful.

At the minute, I can view the encrypted text in Notepad++, but I can't find any sort of schema in the text to show the structure of the file.

If someone could tell me the encryption algorithm that is used to encrypt a .cat file, that would also be useful.

Comment: Why are you talking about encryption instead of parsing? Do you have any reason to believe that it's encrypted? I'd guess it's simply an unencrypted binary file format.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I may be completely wrong, and it may not be encrypted. It may very well be in a binary file format, but researching this has been nearly impossible...

Comment: @Justin I have checked that out, but initially, that is for C++. I have tried p/invoking those functions using C#, but they didn't help me :/

Comment: @CodesInChaos And yes, this is kind of a duplicate. However, the original was posted by me, and I got burnt for not asking my question correctly, so I've tried again.

Comment: @nathanwhite Those functions are the correct functions that you need - if you are having trouble with P/Invoke or they are in some way now working for you then my recommendation would be to ask another question with the specifics of your problem.

Comment: @Justin I didn't have a problem with the p/invoke. The functions worked perfectly, but didn't help me at all.

Comment: @nathanwhite What do you mean by "didn't help me at all"?  You need to be more specific than that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14998/discussion-between-justin-and-nathanwhite)

Comment: Looked at a cat file with a hex editor. Doesn't look encrypted to me, since it clearly has a structure.